# How to check whether the Nodelist hasTag in xml parsing?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

I am parsing one dynamically generated xml, I have some queries regarding the data extraction from the xml. My code is as follows,

```
    try {
      File file = new File("test.xml");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = db.parse(file);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      System.out.println("Root element " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
      NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("control");
      System.out.println("Information of all fields");

      for (int s = 0; s < nodeLst.getLength(); s++) {

        Node fstNode = nodeLst.item(s);

        if (fstNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

          Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;


                  NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value");
              Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
              NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              System.out.println("Value:  "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());


                  NodeList lstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("label");
              Element lstNmElmnt = (Element) lstNmElmntLst.item(0);
              NodeList lstNm = lstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
              System.out.println("Label: " + ((Node) lstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());

NodeList hintElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("hint");
          Element hintElmnt = (Element) hintElmntLst.item(0);
          NodeList hint = hintElmnt.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Hint: " + ((Node) hint.item(0)).getNodeValue());

        }

      }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

**My XML format**

```
    <metadata>

    <control name="first-name">
    <resources lang="en">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <hint>your first name</hint>

    </resources>
<resources lang="fr">
                            <label>Pr├â┬⌐nom</label>
                            <help />
                            <hint>
                                    Votre pr├â┬⌐nom
                            </hint>

                    </resources>
<value> Hari </value>
    </control>


    </metadata>
```

I have the following issues,

1) If hint is present for respective field the only that `<hint>` will be exists in the xml otherwise it wont't exits. So if the tag is not exists then I am getting Error. So How can we check If the tag is exists or not? If tag exists then we will get the tag content.

2) For value field If the field value is not null then it will works fine. If field value is null then the tag in xml will appear like `<value/>` so If field value is null my code is not detecting the `<value/>` tag and getting error. So how can I set the field value as null if it comes with empty value.

Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to check the element nodes you're getting.

If you have `<value />`, then it won't have child nodes:

```
  NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value");
  Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
  if (fstNmElmnt.hasChildNodes()) {
      NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("Value:  "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
  } else {
      System.out.println("Value: null");
  }
```

And if you don't have hint, then you'll get a list of 0 length:

```
  NodeList hintElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("hint");
  if (hintElmntLst.getLength() > 0) {
      Element hintElmnt = (Element) hintElmntLst.item(0);
      NodeList hint = hintElmnt.getChildNodes();
      System.out.println("Hint: " + ((Node) hint.item(0)).getNodeValue());
  }
```

---

**Answer to comment question:** If you want to only read english resources, then simply introduce another loop inside the one you've got:

```
  NodeList resources = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("resources");
  for (int k = 0; k < resources.getLength(); k++) {
      Node resNode = resources.item(k);
      if (resNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          Element resElement = (Element)resNode;
          if (resElement.hasAttribute("lang") &&
                   resElement.getAttribute("lang").equals("en")) {
              //your existing code here for value, label, hint
          }
      }
   }
```

You'll just have to change your code for value, label and hint so that you only access the `resElement`. For example:

```
NodeList fstNmElmntLst = resElement.getElementsByTagName("value");
```

Instead of `fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value");`

Comment: Thank you @Ori Lentz Now I have one more query Let's say, For First Name field If the generated xml has two resources that is one in English language and one more in French language. Now How can I make a condition and get only English type resources? I have updated my xml. Please suggest what should I need to use for comparison.

Comment: Here "fstElmnt" means Document obj "doc" right? I mean instead fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("resources"); I need to make doc.getElementsByTagName("resources");

Comment: No, no, just put it inside your existing for loop (since you want to scan all resources for a given control). place it right after `Element fstElmnt = (Element) fstNode;`

Comment: The condition is working fine. But the value is not coming. I changed resElement.getElementsByTagName("value"); Every thing is coming except value tag entries

Comment: @manjunathramigani sorry for the late reply. I just looked at the xml example you've posted and saw that the `value` tag was outside the resources tag. I must have missed that. anyway, since it is not language-dependent, you should keep it as it was, meaning with `fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value")` (outside the resources loop)

Answer (score 1):

is it ok? If i change it like below ;

Instead of this  ;

```
          NodeList fstNmElmntLst = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("value");
          Element fstNmElmnt = (Element) fstNmElmntLst.item(0);
          NodeList fstNm = fstNmElmnt.getChildNodes();
          System.out.println("Value:  "  + ((Node) fstNm.item(0)).getNodeValue());
```

change it with ;

```
         System.out.println("Value:  " + getTagValue("value", fstElmnt) );
```

And getTagValue method is ;

```
private static String getTagValue(String tag, Element eElement) {
    Node nNode = eElement.getElementsByTagName(tag).item(0);
    if (nNode == null) {
        return null;
    }
    NodeList nlList = nNode.getChildNodes();
    Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);
    if (nValue == null)
        return null;
    return nValue.getNodeValue();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use XPath instead. Code will be *much* easier to read and maintain:

```
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

    NodeList controls = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//control", doc,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < controls.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node c = controls.item(i);
        String label = xp.evaluate(".//label", c);
        String hint = xp.evaluate(".//hint", c);
        String value = xp.evaluate(".//value", c);

        System.out.printf("%s, %s, %s\n", label, hint, value);
    }
```

UPDATE:

To select based on language, just include a predicate on the resources element:

```
        String label = xp.evaluate("resources[@lang='en']/label", c);
        String hint = xp.evaluate("resources[@lang='en']/hint", c);
        String value = xp.evaluate("resources[@lang='en']/value", c);
```

Or, you can of course select the resources element, and then each needed sub-element.

Comment: Note that in order to be sure XPath will work you must parse the XML with namespaces enabled (`dbf.setNamespaceAware(true)` before you call `newDocumentBuilder()`).  XPath is only defined over namespace-well-formed XML, and some implementations give the wrong results on a non-namespace-aware DOM tree (even if the document in question doesn't actually include any namespaces).

Comment: Thank you @forty-two . Now I have one more query Let's say, For First Name field If the generated xml has two resources that is one in English language and one more in French language. Now How can I make a condition and get only English type resources? I have updated my xml. Please suggest what should I need to use for comparison.